# In dictionary, how to decipher entry that contains curly brackets, backslashes, and quotes

Tags: python, json

I was looking through a JSON file that contained multiple dictionary entries similar to the one below. I am in python and cannot find a way to decipher this, and cannot find anything on Google about this. It seems to me to be another dictionary, inside a string, with backslashes. I'm sorry I can't be more descriptive as I am not even sure what to call this.

`{"restrictions":"[{\"type\":\"whitelist\",\"firstFilter\":{\"finder\":\"Criteria\",\"minimum\":\"800000\"}}]"}`

I want to know what type of entry this is called or how I can decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "restrictions": "[
        {
            \"type\": \"whitelist\",
            \"firstFilter\": {
                 \"finder\":\"Criteria\",
                 \"minimum\":\"800000\"
            }
        }
    ]"
}
```

This is a `JSON` object, inside it there is a `str`ing that contains [`JSON`](https://json.org).

---

In Python you can decode it with the `json` library, in this case with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
>>> my_dict = {"restrictions":"[{\"type\":\"whitelist\",\"firstFilter\":{\"finder\":\"Criteria\",\"minimum\":\"800000\"}}]"}
>>> my_json_string = my_dict["restrictions"]
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(my_json_string)
```

Try this, it should work, the result is:

```
[{'type': 'whitelist', 'firstFilter': {'finder': 'Criteria', 'minimum': '800000'}}]
```

---

> *It seems to me to be another dictionary, inside a string, **with backslashes***

The backslashes are used to *escape* some characters, not only in `JSON`:

```
>>> "And they said: "Hello!"" # This will give you an error
>>> "And they said: \"Hello!\"" # This is ok
```